# Setting a Certain page size in Excel

Tags: excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-2013

I am wanting to set page breaks on a sheet to be exactly 11 columns wide and 25 rows high regardless of the cell sizes can this be done? I need this to work in Excel 2007 as that is what the end user will be using. However my work machine runs excel 2010 and my home machine runs excel 2013 which are the two I use to build this file so it would need to be usable in all versions.

If it helps I am needing exactly 48 pages setup and they need to all be directly below the other such that page 1 is A1:K25, page 2 is A26:K50, page 3 A51:K75... etc.

I know I can go to page break view and move the blue bars around but I was hoping for a faster method

Thanks for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you retain the Page Setup, Page, Adjust to: setting rather than defer to the Fit to: xx pages wide by xx pages tall, then you can apply the horizontal page breaks.

```
Dim rw As Long, rws As Long, pgs As Long, lrw As Long, bColor As Boolean
rws = 25: pgs = 48: lrw = (pgs * rws)
With ActiveSheet
    .ResetAllPageBreaks
    .PageSetup.Zoom = 95
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = vbNullString
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$K$" & lrw
    For rw = 1 To lrw Step rws
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Rows(rw + rws)
        .Cells(rw, 1) = "pg " & Int(rw / 25) + 1
        If bColor Then _
            .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(25, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 14
        bColor = Not bColor
    Next rw
    .Cells(rw, 1).Activate
End With
```

The default column widths on my setup wanted to push column K onto another page so I adjusted the zoom to 95%. This may need to be adjusted by you according to page orientation, fonts, column widths, etc. Even the make and model of the printer used can factor in.

Comment: Very interesting. I like the addition of color and page number for reference however I do not wont them for my code. So I removed those sections. As well as the last line that activates a cell. However the Vertical page break appears between Col I and J until I adjusted the zoom to 250 then it included Col K. Could we not just use the same style of code you did for the HPage Breaks and apply it to VPage Breaks? I have tried and can not get it to work right. I do not get any errors but the dotted line remains between Col I and J.  Here is what I tried .VPageBreaks.Add Before: =Range("L2")